# Registration page HTML not sending form data to php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, registration

I've been making a registration page for my site and trying to figure out why this code always seems to echo "Nothing submitted yet" after I press the register button.  Is there an issue with the way the HTML forms are coded?  Or with the way the php is receiving them?

```
<?php
session_start();

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if (isset($_POST['uname'])) {

    include_once("dbconnect.php");

    $uname = strip_tags($_POST["uname"]);
    $pwd = strip_tags($_POST["pword"]);
    $pwdtwo = strip_tags($_POST["pwordtwo"]);

    $unamecheck = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $usname);
    $pwdcheck = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $paswd);

    $msg = "Something submitted!";

    // Are the username and password legal?
    if($pwd == $pwdcheck && $unamecheck == $uname) {
      // Is the password confirmed?
      if($pwd == $pwdtwo){
          $sql = "SELECT userID, username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$usname' LIMIT 1";
          $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
          $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
          // Check to make sure that the username doesn't already exist.
          if(is_null($row[1])){
              $uricheck = strrchr($uname, "@");
              $uriedu = "@my.uri.edu";
              // Check that it is a uri email account.
              if($uricheck !== false && strcmp($uricheck, $uriedu) === 0){
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO `campuskey`.`users` (`userID`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$uname', '$pwd')";
                  mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
                  // Set session variables
                  $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
                  $msg = "You have now registered!";
                  // Now direct to users feed
                  header("Location: user.php");
              } else {
                   $msg = "That is not a valid uri email.";
                  }

          } else {
              $msg = "That email is already in use, fuckface!";
              }
          }
          else {
            $msg = "Either you have typing tourettes or your keyboard's fucked up.  Those passwords don't match up";
            }
    } else {
        $msg = "<h2>What the fuck did you type?  That shit ain't legal!</h2>";
        }
} else {
    $msg = "Nothing submitted yet.";
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Campus Key, Page</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <a href="index.html"> <img src="logowhite.png" alt="Campus Key" style="width:150px;height:41px"></a>
            </header>

            <nav class="navigation">
                <div class="non_registerd">
                    <h2><a class="button" href="login.php">Already have an account? Login here!</a></h2>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <form>
                <?php
                  echo $msg;
                 ?><br>
                URI Email: <input class="input" id="email" type="text" name="uname" placeholder="your@my.uri.edu" size="30" required><br>
                Password: <input class="input" id="pass" type="text" name="pword" size="30" required><br>
                Confirm Password: <input class="input" type="text" name="pwordtwo" size="30" required><br>
                <input class="button" type="Submit" name="submit" value="Register"><br>
            </form>
        </body>
    <footer>
        <p><FONT color="#ffffff">Campus Key &copy Whatever We Want</color></p>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: I like your error messages ;)

Comment: Form default to GET when the method is omitted, remember that.

Answer (score 1):

Your form tag does not contain any Action or Method atrr
you must define them first like this :

```
     <form  method="POST"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the form element correctly.

Since there is a password field in the form, you would like to use the POST method (so the values are hidden), like you did on the PHP side.

On the HTML side you didn't specify the method attribute. The defaulft method is GET. This is why you can't fetch the data with your PHP.

Use the following instead;

`<form method="POST">`